# How to map an API call object correctly to a Java object?

Tags: java

I am working to retrieve data from an API call. For the login part, a simple text response is sent by the site to which I am connecting.

Sample response is given below:

```
{"code": "OK", 
"data": {"session_id": "myemail@domain.com:uJoaY1KlTWBchJpGHeZVZWs3"}, 
"user": "myemail@domain.com"}
```

I want to extract the various values from above response. What kind of object do I have to create that maps correctly to each of the elements in the response? Also, I thought of using a hashmap as part of my object- is that the correct approach? What is the best way to map the above data to a Java object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That data is in [JSON](http://json.org) format. There are several Java libraries to parse JSON data, for example [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).